# Open graph object properties could not be updated in Yammer

Tags: api, yammer

I am consuming Yammer API to post data on user's wall in Yammer.

But I am getting response as:

```
{
  "action_id": 13730xxx,
  "object_id": 35156120732xxxx,
  "actor_id": 1552130xxx,
  "warnings": [
    "Open graph object properties could not be updated: [\"Open graph object already claimed by another client application (597xx)\"]"
  ]
}
```

And the data posted on yammer's wall is very old one. Its not updated. Please help me to figure out why I am not able to post correct data.

Payload i posted:

```
{
  "activity": {
    "actor": {
      "name": "Appreciated @ ABC",
      "email": "abc@xyz.in"
    },
    "action": "update",
    "object": {
      "url": "http://www.xyz.in",
      "title": "MNO Appreciated JKL @ QWE",
      "image": "https://www.google.com/xyz.png"
    },
    "Private": false,
    "message": "Well Done"
  }
}
```